# ERROR 1062 (23000) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm searching to convert a table from CHARACTER SET utf8 to utf8mb4.

I execute this command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and I have this error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 935: Duplicate entry 'public' for key 'uri'.

I have only one *'public'* string in *uri column*.

How I can resolve this?

Thanks.